# Is there any python inbuilt module exist which can vary the output size and style?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, font-size, font-style, termcolor

I am trying to enlarge the size of output code. Currently I am working on vs code on window. I am a quite beginner. I also want some advance functionality on my source code.

CODE:

I want to print a table of 1 to 100 counting as presentable as I can.[Here is the source code ,Here I use termcolor to bold and color text. And board is simply a list of 1 to 100 number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSrW.png)

OUTPUT:

[Here is the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPs3.png)

please suggest some advance changes which can make it more presentable including how to enlarge the text and change its style.

**Little Help**

Comment: The font size of a shell / terminal is configured in the shell / terminal and cannot be controlled by your program.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it's impossible, you only can modify the appearance of terminal. You can modify these configurations and so on which start with `terminal.integrated.` in the settings.json file:

```
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Courier New",
  "terminal.integrated.lineHeight": 5,
  "terminal.integrated.fontWeight": "100",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 20,
  "terminal.integrated.fontWeightBold": "900"
```